# The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1 error while updating jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to update jsonb column in java with mybatis.

Following is my mapper method

```
@Update("update service_user_assn set external_group = external_group || '{\"service_name\": \"#{service_name}\" }' where user=#{user} " + 
                " and service_name= (select service_name from services where service_name='Google') " )
public int update(@Param("service_name")String service_name,@Param("user") Integer user);
```

I am getting the following error while updating the jsonb (external_group) cloumn.

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
### The error may involve com.apds.mybatis.mapper.ServiceUserMapper.update-Inline
```

I am able to update with the same way for non-jsonb columns.

Also if I am putting hardcoded value it's working for jsonb columns.

How to solve this error while updating jsonb column?

Answer (score 0):

You should not enclose `#{}` in single quotes because it will become part of a literal rather than a placeholder. i.e.

```sql
external_group = external_group || '{"service_name": "?"}' where ...
```

So, there will be only one placeholder in the `PreparedStatement` and you get the error.

The correct way is to concatenate the `#{}` in SQL.
You may also need to cast the literal to `jsonb` type explicitly.

```java
@Update({
  "update service_user_assn set",
  "external_group = external_group",
  "|| ('{\"service_name\": \"' || #{service_name} || '\" }')::jsonb",
  "where user=#{user} and",
  "service_name= (select service_name from services where service_name='Google')"})
```

The SQL being executed would look as follows.

```sql
external_group = external_group || ('{"service_name": "' || ? || '"}')::jsonb where ...
```

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL and above syntax is not working.

Comment: @sagar.tarle Please create a minimum executable project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and share it on GitHub. Then I'll look into it.

Comment: @sagar.tarle It seems that you need to cast the literal to `jsonb` type explicitly. Please see the updated answer.